# Please help me check for duplicates in hosts file using linux terminal

Tags: linux, file, duplicates, ping, plaintext

I would like to know if there is a way of removing any duplicate lines in a host file that needs a specific formating. This is an example of what i mean the first part has to be left alone but the second part needs every line compared with every and all other lines and duplicates removed oh the file is big almost 1GB.

Also with the script that any one suggests could i use ping to check every line in the second part for its existence on the Internet and remove if doesn't exist and place all this edited info into a new file name.

```
{FIRST PART}  {SECOND PART}
 127.0.0.1        WWW.BLAHDOTTEST,COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.HHHHHH.COM 
 127.0.0.1        WWW.JJJJJJ.COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.PPPPPPP.COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.BLAHDOTTEST,COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.HHHHHH.COM
```

so the new file would look like this assuming all these address were valid ones.

```
{FIRST PART}  {SECOND PART}
 127.0.0.1        WWW.BLAHDOTTEST,COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.JJJJJJ.COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.PPPPPPP.COM
 127.0.0.1        WWW.HHHHHH.COM
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
sort -u /etc/hosts > /tmp/hosts.new && mv /tmp/hosts.new /etc/hosts
```

That's assuming you know that you're in control of the machine, and no
other user will tamper with files in /tmp.

As for the ping: That's impossible given that you have them in your hosts-file pointing to the loop-back interface.  Anything in hosts will always be valid. (unless you tear lo down, in which case ALL will fail.)

If you can do w/o the funky large hosts file for a few minutes you could mv it out of the way (leaving system relevant entries behind) and do something naive like the following if dupes have been pulled out already:

As your own user, do the following:

```
vi cleaner
i
<copy & paste script now>
ESC
:wq
chmod +x cleaner
cp /etc/hosts .
./cleaner
```

Once it's done, have a look at newfile (in your home). If you're happy with that, copy it to /etc/hosts

```
sudo cp newfile /etc/hosts
```

This is what goes into **cleaner** :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  IP=$( echo $line| awk '{print $2}' )
  if $( ping -c 1 -W 2 $IP >> errors 2>&1 ); then
    echo $line >> newfile
  fi 
done < hosts
```

P.S.:  If you're going to maintain a Linux/Unix box it's high time you learnt some basics.

Comment: Thanks for your time your answer worked a treat.
But that command does not do my second question witch was is there a way to use the program ping to validated the address and remove the ones that are n longer valid???

Comment: See the edit.  Short of taking the matching line out of  /etc/hosts, pinging, and adding it back if it's still up it can't be done trivially.

Comment: OK i thought they may have been a way to execute some sort of script to ignore the first part but i see your point.

Comment: OK i thought they may have been a way to execute some sort of script to ignore the first part but i see your point.
Do you know of a way to remove the first part and then pinging the list and automatically removing the dead address i have got about 40000 lines to check....

Comment: wow cool thank you. I have to admit i am still a noob when it comes to the code you put up.
How do i make the code run i have put it into gedit and I don't know what to save it as so i can run it from the terminal window. Also how do i run it on my copy of host file that i have on my desktop at the moment its called rich2.txt so how can i run the code you gave me on this file??

Comment: Please help me again i cant seem to mack it work.. all i get is either an error message saying    line 8: hosts: No such file or directory or just a blank flashing prompt...

Comment: Or it just deletes the content of the file. I must be doing something wrong. Please tell me how to Implement your script with every step included because I'm still a noob when it comes to scripts.